# Graphing and Presenting Data

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Less technical question today:

What are the best ways for grouping a df for multiple graphs in different areas in python?

I need to create a 'Quarterly Presentation' and suck at graphing in excel.

I cleaned my df need to be able to slice by date, sum by sale per year, sale by month and compare to last year, do YTD numbers, etc...

Also, want to be able to do this by Product type and Packaging type. Top 5 by customer, total sales, profit, etc...

Created a multi-Index by year and month for Sales, Cost and GP numbers, but slicing or using .xs or unstack to plot is giving me shit options for creating good graphs.

How do people group data for maximum flexibility and the best plotting potential?

Better visual

Index is date of sale

columns=['Customer', 'Sale amount', 'Title of product', 'Product', 'Package Type', Quantity', 'Cost', 'Profit']

20,000 rows

Any tips/videos on financial data presentation using Jupyter/Python?

Answer (score 0):

For data conditioning and loading in data (i.e loading .csv files): 
**Use the [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/) and [NumPy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/) libraries**

For creating lightweight, non-interactive plots that can be easily downloaded: 
**Use the [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) library**

For creating interactive plots (i.e support zooming and data hovering): 
**Use the  [Plotly](https://plotly.com/python/) library**

If you need any specific help once you start writing the code, feel free to ask another question and I would be glad to help!

Comment: I have written the code cleaning up the data. 

Final lines look like this: 
main_cogs = main_cogs.set_index('Date')
fin_graph = main_cogs.groupby([(main_cogs.index.year), 
                                                      (main_cogs.index.month)]).sum()

This is one small part of what I need to, obviously.

Comment: This issue is I can't slice the data in the Multi_Index above so I can use it as the data in the two rects variables. It says the shape won't match. 

https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-barchart-py

Slicing used: 
#Didn't work in getting the data separate to match in graph
# fs_19 = fin_graph.loc[2019, slice(7), All]['Sales'] 
# fs_20 = fin_graph.loc[2020, slice(7), All]['Sales']

I tried to used these variables to graph it.

Comment: @chasedcribbet Could you please post your code and some example outputs in another question? The formatting there is better than in these comments, thus easier to understand. Thanks!

Comment: I will post it soon